# CSS selector inner element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a menu generated by an ecommerce software, and I need to make bold the main categories.

I have tried these two and others selection but I can't select the right element (the ones in capital letters "COLLECTION" and "CATEGORIES" as shown in the picture)

```
li.ty-text-links__item ty-level-1
{
    font-weight:bold;
}

ty-text-links__item ty-level-1 > a {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show a demo of what you are doing?

Comment: Can you try using `!important`?

Comment: If you forget the dot `.` to define classes, you are selecting a TAG

Comment: Hi Sorry but I can't show a demo. I'm working on my local pc for now.

Comment: is this `ty-text-links__item` a class or tag if class than you have to put `.` infront of it

Answer (score 2):

Your styles are not being applied to the element. Because, you forgot the `.` of the class notation before `ty-level-1` class in CSS.

```
li.ty-text-links__item .ty-level-1 {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.ty-text-links__item .ty-level-1 > a {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you target the `anchor link` directly instead like this:

```
a.ty-text__a {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Or like this:

```
.ty-text-links__item a.ty-text__a {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Or like this:

```
.ty-text-links__item > a {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: is that `fontweight` or `font-weight`

Answer (score 0):

I have added the dots as suggested by Marcos this way and this works

Sorry for the stupid question

```
.ty-text-links__item .ty-level-1 > a {
    font-weight:bold;
} and
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
li.ty-text-links__item.ty-level-1 a.ty-text-links__a {
font-weight:bold;
```

}